# Does Joshua the high priest make the list of figures of Messiah in the Bible?

Tags: messiah

There are unequivocal figures in the bible that point to Christ, namely;

Micah 5:2

> But you, Bethlehem Ephrathah, though you be little among the thousands
>   of Judah, yet out of you shall he come forth unto me that is to be
>   ruler in Israel; whose goings forth have been from of old, from
>   everlasting.

Zechariah 9:9

> Rejoice greatly, O daughter of Zion; shout, O daughter of Jerusalem:
>   behold, thy King cometh unto thee: he is just, and having salvation;
>   lowly, and riding upon an ass, and upon a colt the foal of an ass.

Not forgetting Isaiah 9:6 and plenty more.

The question is, does Joshua the high priest make this list of figures considering the peculiar terms mentioned below concerning him ?

Zechariah 6:12

> ‘Behold, a man whose name is the Branch, and He will branch out from
>   His place and build the temple of the LORD.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  I don't understand what you're asking?  When you say "figures" do you mean metaphors for, or descriptions of?  Are you asking if Joshua the High Priest created all these metaphors, used throughout history?  Thanks!

Comment: @JBH In a few places in scriptures, Messiah is prophesied  to come into the world using metaphors or descriptions, or in figures, as I indicated.  I am asking if Joshua as well characterized the person of Messiah, judging from the peculiar language used on him by God.